# Efficiently hashing all the files of a directory (1000 2MB files)

Tags: java, memory, hash, memory-leaks, md5

I would like to hash (MD5) all the files of a given directory, which holds 1000 2MB photos.
I tried just running a for loop and hashing a file at a time, but that caused memory issues.

I need a method to hash each file in an efficient manner (memory wise).

I have posted 3 questions with my problem, but now instead of fixing my code, I want to see what would be the best general approach to my requirement.

Thank you very much for the help.

```
public class MD5 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("/Users/itaihay/Desktop/test");
    for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
        try {
            model.MD5.hash(f);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.

        }
    }

private static MessageDigest md;
private static BufferedInputStream fis;
private static byte[] dataBytes;
private static byte[] mdbytes;

private static void clean() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    dataBytes = new byte[8192];
}
public static void hash(File file) {
    try {
        clean();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        int nread = 0;
        while ((nread = fis.read(dataBytes)) != -1) {
            md.update(dataBytes, 0, nread);
        }
        nread = 0;
        mdbytes = md.digest();  System.out.println(javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(mdbytes).toLowerCase());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fis.close();
            dataBytes = null;
            md = null;
            mdbytes = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }       
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your code?  We can't tell how to optimize your code if we don't know what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, using built-in Java MD5 code, you should be able to keep your memory footprint very small.  I do something similar when hashing a large number of Jar files (up to a few MB apiece, usually 500MB-worth at a time) and get decent performance.  You'll definitely want to play around with different buffer sizes until you find the optimal size for your system configuration.  The following code-snippet uses no more than `bufSize+128` bytes at a time, plus a negligible amount of overhead for the `File`, `MessageDigest`, and `InputStream` objects used to compute the md5 hash:

```
InputStream is = null;
File f = ...
int bufSize = ...
byte[] md5sum = null;

try {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    is = new FileInputStream(f);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufSize];

    int read = 0;
    while((read = is.read(buffer)) > 0) digest.update(buffer,0,read);
    md5sum = digest.digest();
} catch (Exception e){
} finally {
    try{
        if(is != null) is.close();
    } catch (IOException e){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Increasing your Java heap space could solve it short term.

Long term, you want to look into reading images into a fixed-size queue that can fit in the memory. Don't read them all in at once. Enqueue the most recent image and dequeue the earliest image.

Answer (score 0):

MD5 updates its state in 64 byte chunks, so you only need 16 bytes of a file in memory at a time. The MD5 state itself is 128 bits, as is the output size.

The most memory conservative approach would be to read 64 bytes at a time from each file, file-by-file, and use it to update that file's MD5 state. You would need at most 999 * 16 + 64 = 16048 ~= 16k of memory.

But such small reads would be very inefficient, so from there you can increase the read size from a file to fit within your memory constraints.